# Improving tooltip performance but now does not work in IE7 or IE6 jquery and inline styles

Tags: jquery, performance

I have created a tooltip that appends a DIV with text to the page.

I have managed to get it to appear in the position i want and follow the mouse as it moves.

I was previously doing this with inline styles and updating the top, left absolute positioning co-ordinates dynamically inline.

This seems to cause performance issues so i wrote the dynamic styling to a `<style>` in the `<head>` of the dosument which works fine in Firefox but now not in IE7 or IE6.

The jsFiddle is here;

http://jsfiddle.net/SBhnc/7/

I guess i need to remove the  tag from the  on mouseout as well but IE seems to render it once and then always again in the same position.

I would obviously like it to work in all browsers and not suffer any massive performance hits like it was when writing inline styles.

Comment: If you view this fork - http://jsfiddle.net/5YKNS/ Then run the mouse over the tooltip holders alot then you should see the performance slow down i was experiencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly where to start, so how about [my changes](http://jsfiddle.net/5YKNS/1/)?  As you can see, it now works just fine in Internet Explorer.  Explanations for each change:

- Internet Explorer allows a maximum number of StyleSheets (31 or 32, I think) and on your mousemove event you were appending a new `<style>` element to the head.  When it reaches the limit the tooltip never moves again.  I switched it back to *css()* for you.
- Every time you mouseover the elements, you attach a new mousemove event.  The problem here is that you *never* unbind this handler, so mouse off, mouse on causes a new handler to be attached each time, doubling the work being done and over-stressing the browser (poor IE!).  I moved the *mouseover* handler to it's own space where it's only created and attached once.
- Each mouseover would create the tooltip, then on mouseoff you detach it.  Much better to have it in the DOM to start with, just *hide()* and *show()* it.
- You don't do *any* caching of selectors or variables.  Each time you write `$('#tooltip')` it's an extra lookup.  Save the result of `$('#tooltip')` to a variable and use the variable.

I did some of the work caching `$('#tooltip')`, but you should do the same for `$(this)`.  *mousemove* is a fairly stressful event, and can be called many times within a few ms.  This causes slowdown on the rendering because it waits for the script to complete.

Comment: that's great Andy.  Really appreciated.  As much as i am learning about actually writing the code it really helps to know how to optimise it as well and this has been a valuable insight.

Comment: @Ryan: no worries :-) You might also want to look at implementing your tooltip as a plugin, which would make it a little more portable.  Search Google for "jQuery plugin tutorial" and you should be able to find something to get you started.